# Regex escaping for Mongo DB in eval

Tags: regex, mongodb, bash, escaping, eval

This is my first query which I am running from bash using eval and its working perfectly fine. Please find below.

```
mongo --username ${dbuser} --password ${dbpassword} --authenticationDatabase=admin --eval "db.${collectionname}.remove({Email: /[^\x00-\x7F]+/});" ${dbname}
```

I have one more query which removes the invalid email, I tried various escape sequences but its not working for me every time it gives me a syntax error.

```
mongo --username ${dbuser} --password ${dbpassword} --authenticationDatabase=admin --eval "db.company.find({Email: {$not: /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/}});" ${dbname}
```

After escaping all possible characters:

```
mongo --username ${dbuser} --password ${dbpassword} --authenticationDatabase=admin --eval "db.com.remove({Email: {$not:{\/\^\(\(\[\^\<\>\(\)\\\[\\\]\\\\\.,;\:\\s@\"\]\+\(\\\.\[\^\<\>\(\)\\\[\\\]\\\\\.,;\:\\s@\"\]\+\)\*\)\|\(\"\.\+\"\)\)@\(\(\\\[\[0\-9\]\{1,3\}\\\.\[0\-9\]\{1,3\}\\\.\[0\-9\]\{1,3\}\\\.\[0\-9\]\{1,3\}\\\]\)\|\(\(\[a\-zA\-Z\\\-0\-9\]\+\\\.\)\+\[a\-zA\-Z\]\{2,\}\)\)\$\/i}});" leadsdb
```

Now getting this error:

```
2020-05-31T08:32:53.860-0400 E  QUERY    [js] uncaught exception: SyntaxError: expected property name, got ':' :
@(shell eval):1:23
2020-05-31T08:32:53.860-0400 E  -        [main] exiting with code -4
```

After correction what was suggested in a comment (/), these should not be escaped in the start and in the end of the regex

```
mongo --username ${dbuser} --password ${dbpassword} --authenticationDatabase=admin --eval "db.com.remove({Email: {$not:/\^\(\(\[\^\<\>\(\)\\\[\\\]\\\\\.,;\:\\s@\"\]\+\(\\\.\[\^\<\>\(\)\\\[\\\]\\\\\.,;\:\\s@\"\]\+\)\*\)\|\(\"\.\+\"\)\)@\(\(\\\[\[0\-9\]\{1,3\}\\\.\[0\-9\]\{1,3\}\\\.\[0\-9\]\{1,3\}\\\.\[0\-9\]\{1,3\}\\\]\)\|\(\(\[a\-zA\-Z\\\-0\-9\]\+\\\.\)\+\[a\-zA\-Z\]\{2,\}\)\)\$/i}});" leadsdb
```

Output still getting the same error:

```
2020-05-31T09:10:55.461-0400 E  QUERY    [js] uncaught exception: SyntaxError: expected property name, got ':' :
@(shell eval):1:23
2020-05-31T09:10:55.461-0400 E  -        [main] exiting with code -4
```

Escaped the following characters using this tool [here](https://www.regex-escape.com/preg_quote-online.php) also tried the same thing manually earlier but getting the same error

```
. \ + * ? [ ^ ] $ ( ) { } = ! < > | : -
```

Can anyone please help me in escaping this query for MongoDB shell. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What syntax error is it showing?

Comment: ./test.sh: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `('

Comment: After escaping all ')' and '"' (double quotes) now getting this error: 2020-05-31T08:16:45.219-0400 E  QUERY    [js] uncaught exception: SyntaxError: expected property name, got ':' :
@(shell eval):1:23

Comment: Updated the question please check

Comment: I corrected it, but still getting the same results. The question has been updated please check.

Comment: Just go with this `/^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/`

Comment: Please go through [this](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/not/) link. You're probably missing some braces or something.

Comment: I used the same regex that you provided but still facing same issue.

Comment: And I am already following the link you provided. But something is doing due to soo many special characters in the regex because the other regex is working perfectly file as I mentioned in my comment.

Comment: Is there any way I could reproduce your problem at my end. It'll help me debug your problem better. Because this is surely because of some mismatches.

Comment: Yes you can reproduce this issue if you have MongoDB server installed on your local machine https://www.mongodb.com/download-center/community and then you create a sample database and collection having Email property and try running import: mongo --eval "db.collectioname.find({Email: {$not: /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/}});" dbname